# Implementing different levels of drag/drop functionality?

Tags: usability, gui-design, interaction-design, navigation, responsive-design

I'm working on a tablet app for a motel. Initially, the app was going to be tested on one floor. Essentially, the app would be used to move guests from one room/bed to another room/bed.

As you can see from the very simple screenshot, I can drag/drop Joe from Room 301-#1 to Room 303-#2. Or I can drag/drop Joe within Room 301: From #1 to #2. Overall, in the tablet you can see every room from one floor. In here, it works great.

The issue now is that the app will be used for several floors. I really like the drag/drop functionality, but I don't know how I can drag/drop from different floors. For example, let's say I want to drag/drop Joe from Room 301-#1 to Room 404 #2. How can I show that graphically using this drag/drop interface.

I'm trying to find creative ideas that can be used for this. It needs to be simple, and as simple as it may sound, it would be to move Joe from his current room 301 #1 to room 405 #3 with just one movement/swype.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows operating systems, I can drag-and-drop files between active windows by dragging the file in question to the taskbar, pausing over the application I'm targeting to cause it to become active, then dropping the file in the desired window.

Similarly, you could add a "floor selection" row of buttons so that it filters your view by floor, then mimic this same behavior.

[image: with floor selection]

Answer (score 0):

1. You know whom you want to move
2. You want to know on which floor the available positions are before starting to drag

You could start by dragging the person to a temporary position, say at the top in a place like where maxathousand has shown '1,2,3,4,5' buttons. Then you could swipe/ slide the screen to view other floors. When you have decided the destination floor, you perform another drag-drop - this time from the top row into the available position.

One single drag-drop swipe and to hold on until you decide the drop destination may seem less usable in your scenario where you want to swap screens.

Drag and drop works efficient when you are able to see pick and drop destinations all in one screen.